# Can the Skald's Armour power be used to make a creature attack itself?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Can the Skald's Armour power be used to make a creature attack itself?

> **Power  Daily (Immediate Interrupt)**
>   Trigger: An enemy targets you with a melee attack.
>   Effect: The triggering enemy instead targets a creature of your choice adjacent to you.

Full details at [DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2519).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If it's adjacent to you, yes.**

It just targets "a creature of your choice adjacent to you". If it was intended to exclude the triggering foe it would say, "*another* creature of your choice adjacent to you" (or, as mentioned by doppelgreener below, "an enemy... other than the attacker"). I would imagine that the power was deliberately written to include the triggering foe so that it could be used when only a single foe was attacking you in melee.

Comment: Another power in the PHB2, Deflecting Thunder (p36), says: _"... instead targets an enemy adjacent to you other than the attacker."_ (As far as I can find, Skald's Armor and Deflecting Thunder are the only powers of their kind.)